# Scope undefined in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I'm trying to access the value of scope, but it shows it as undefined, and I need to show me the value that the user inserts.

My HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as model">
     <input type="text"  ng-model="model.cero" ng-cero="">    
    </div>
```

In JS

```
angular
    .module("myApp",[])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
     var model=this;
    })
    .directive ('ngCero', function($parse){
      var linkFunction =function(scope, element, attrs){
         element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
        if(event.which === 44 || event.which === 13) {
              console.log( $parse(attrs.format));   
          }
        });
      };
      return{
         restrict : 'A',
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved

```
angular
    .module("myApp",[])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
        var model=this;
    })
    .directive ('ngCero', function($parse){
        var linkFunction =function(scope, element, attrs){
                              element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
                              if(event.which === 44 || event.which === 13) {
                                  console.log( $parse(attrs.format));   
                              }
                              });
                          };
      return{
          restrict : 'A',
          scope:{
                  cero:"ngModel"
                },
          link: linkFunction
      }
})
```